# How to annotate a constructor function with an interface

Tags: typescript

In the following code:

```
interface Person {}
interface PersonConstructor {
    new (): Person;
}

let Person: PersonConstructor = function () {};
let person: Person = new Person();
```

I get the error message:

```
[ts]
Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'PersonConstructor'.
Type '() => void' provides no match for the signature 'new (): Person'.
```

What is the right way of annotating a constructor function with an interface?

Comment: Heavy-handed use of type assertions probably?  It looks like they [don't want to support this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2310) for TypeScript code.

Comment: Does this code work in pure JavaScript (without any type annotations)?

Comment: @cerberus, yes it does. The un-annotated code looks like this: `let Person = function () {}; let person = new Person();`